# Jquery Validation Being Specific

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an enrollment no field as below

```
<div class="section colm colm6">
<label for="enrollno" class="field-label">Enrollment Number</label>
<label for="enrollno" class="field prepend-icon">
<input type="number" name="enrollno" id="enrollno" class="gui-input" placeholder="Your Enrollment Number...">
<b class="tooltip tip-left"><em> Enter Your Enrollment Number Here</em></b>
<label class="field-icon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></label>  
</label>
</div>
```

And i applied validation rules as follows

```
rules: {


enrollno: {
    required: true,
    minlength: 13,
    maxlength: 13

        },      

      },


messages:{


enrollno: {
    required: 'Enter your enrollment number',
    minlength: 'Enrollment no must be 13 characters',
    maxlength: 'Enrollment no is only upto 13 characters',

         }, 


    },
```

Now i want to add one more rule ., that is the Enrollment Number should be with following rules :

1. Total 13 digits which is already set and working
2. 3rd digit should be an alphabet only
3. 4th digit is either numeric or alphabet
4. Rest all are numbers

Kindly guide me doing it please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `regex` , you have to build your own rule for that check [regex manual](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_regexp.asp) or [check this link](http://www.jquery4u.com/syntax/jquery-basic-regex-selector-examples/) it has some examples. Check this 
  [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/c8pxX/1/).

Comment: Did you see the inks? i have posted in answer.

Comment: yup i saw ., how to choose character number in it like 3ed char should be... i am trying but no use :(

Comment: what would be your enrollment number? example?

Comment: 11AT111111111
the fourth one T can also be number that is 4th one is alphanumeric and 3rd one is alphabet rest are numbers only

Comment: Updated to answer ,please check demo link.